# How to Apply Unique in Date Class in data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table, lubridate

I have a problem to deal with `Date` class in `data.table`.  Assuming I have:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)    
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), BD = as_date(c("2012-5-6", "2012-5-6", "2012-5-6", NA, NA, "2012-5-19", NA, NA, NA)))
```

return,

```
   ID         BD
1:  1 2012-05-06
2:  1 2012-05-06
3:  1 2012-05-06
4:  2       <NA>
5:  2       <NA>
6:  2 2012-05-19
7:  3       <NA>
8:  3       <NA>
9:  3       <NA>
```

Now `NA` becomes `Date` class so I can use the following code to unique:

```
dt[, ifelse(all(is.na(BD)), as_date(NA), unique(BD)), by = ID]
```

it returns as follows:

```
   ID    V1
1:  1 15466
2:  2    NA
3:  3    NA
```

I expect to have the following result:

```
   ID         V1
1:  1 2012-05-06
2:  2 2012-05-19
3:  3       <NA>
```

Could you please give suggestions?

Comment: Use `if ... else ...` instead of `ifelse` (you should carefully study the help page). Apparently, you want this: `dt[, if(all(is.na(BD))) as_date(NA) else na.omit(unique(BD)), by = ID]`

Comment: Another option is put `NA` rows at end and than get unique rows by ID: `dt[order(is.na(BD))][!duplicated(ID)]`

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this helps:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(
    BD = min(BD, na.rm = T)
  )
```

You will get a warning message because all values in one group are NA. Otherwise,  it works.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     ID BD        
  <dbl> <date>    
1     1 2012-05-06
2     2 2012-05-19
3     3 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
unique(setorder(dt, ID, BD,na.last=TRUE), by="ID")
```

Also, keeping your code:

```
dt2 <- dt[, ifelse(all(is.na(BD)), as_date(NA), unique(BD)), by = ID][, V1:=as.Date(V1, origin=ymd("19700101"))]
```